# Joining points to polygons in geopandas creating an empty dataframe even though overlapping on geoplot

Tags: polygon, point, geopandas

I have a text file where there are longitude and latitudes and the special IDs of the points I need to process. Let's assume text file looks like a bunch of lines like below:

```
-75.3530    41.830902   1
```

I read this file as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
point_df=pd.read_csv('point_file.txt', delimiter='\s+', header=None, index_col=False)
point_df.rename(columns = {0:'longitude', 1:'latitude', 2:'id' }, inplace = True)
```

I convert this file into a geodataframe in order to process it with the polygon data I have as below:

```
from geopandas import geodataframe
from shapely.geometry import Point
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(point_df.longitude, point_df.latitude)]
point_df=point_df.drop(['latitude', 'longitude'], axis=1)
point_df=GeoDataFrame(point_df, geometry=geometry, crs="EPSG:4326")
```

Next I read my polygon dataframe (a file with .shp extension) as follows:

```
import geopandas as gpd
polygon_df=gpd.read_file('hereismypolydata.shp')
```

I check my polygon dataframe with `polygon_df.crs` and see that the crs is EPSG 4326 like my point_df. My polygon dataframe looks as follows:

```
POLY_ID    geometry
1          POLYGON ((2728701.903 599036.272, 2728907.551 ...
```

Furthermore, I inspect them with `geoplot` package with the following code to see if they overlap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gp
import geoplot as gplt
%matplotlib inline

ax=gplt.polyplot(polygon_df)
gplt.pointplot(point_df, ax=ax)
```

Based on the produced plot, these two are overlapping. So I expect that when I join them, I am going to get the dataframe I need. And I try the following line to spatially join them:

```
joined_dataframe=gpd.sjoin(point_df, polygon_df, how='inner', op='intersects')
```

This dataframe is fully empty even though there is at least one point and polygon intersecting. I have also tried 'within' command and rather than inner, I tried to keep all rows to see if there is anything with 'left', but whatever is merging is just NaN.

I do not have custom datasets I am permitted to put for reproducibility purposes (I will try to create later on) but what would be the reason that the joined data frame is returning empty? I am new to geospatial data and packages with Python and any insight/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the geometry of the polygon dataframe, it appears that the CRS is not actually EPSG:4326, whose coordinates should represent [decimal degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).

You will need to determine the correct CRS, which once found can be set and then converted with:

```
polygon_df = polygon_df.set_crs(crs, allow_override=True).to_crs("EPSG:4326")
```

It looks like the polygon dataframe may be using a projected CRS, something like [EPSG:3857](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection).